# Should [health] be ignored or burninated?

Tags: discussion, tags

For now I'm putting [health](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health) on my ignore list because it looks like stuff there is almost always off-topic.

Thoughts on whether it should be completely removed (i.e. burninated)?

Comment: You might need to justify if [these high-scored questions tagged with `health` tag](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health?sort=votes&pageSize=15) aren't related/don't need that tag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As [a comment](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2737/should-health-be-ignored-or-burninated#comment3740_2737) pointed out, there are [high-scored, on-topic questions under the tag](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health?sort=votes&pageSize=15).

You've rightly identified what posts are off-topic: great! The best way to handle off-topic questions is to [cast a close vote](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions). That will help point people to the [tour](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/tour) that shows what types of questions are on-topic at Lifehacks.